# How can I create this type of line-work?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, drawing

[image: swirly lines]

I came across this beautiful piece on pinterest (unsure who the artist is, please link me if you know).

I wanted to ask how to create lines like these. In particular - how did the artist create gaps within a singular line path?

Example of the gaps ->  ______ _ **_ _______ _** _______

Comment: What have you tried? What has failed?  There's no way to know for sure how the artist did it without asking. It could be completely hand drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard work method, no 3D, no pattern brushes, blendings nor other flashy functions.

Have smart guides and snap to points on, no other snaps. In the preferences prevent stroke scaling. Have rounded stroke ends in use. Curves should have a stroke, but no fill.

[image]

1. Draw a circle
2. Split the circle to halves with the scissors tool
3. Move the halves as shown - they have one common point. Combine the halves to a group to keep them easily together.
4. Draw a curve
5. Duplicate the curve several times or draw new slightly different curves to get an array which resembles a surface
6. Select one curve at a time, split it with the scissors tool at a crossing point and remove the excessive part which should be hidden
7. Place  a copy of the group from phase 3 to the needed places. Scale and rotate it with the normal seletion tool and fix the ends onto the long curves with the direct selection tool. Split the curves with the scissors and remove pieces to make holes.

ADD: the stroke in your example seems to have varying width. I can tell 2 possiblities to get it:

- use the stroke width tool or
- outline strokes, when you are otherwise ready and make some warpings (=the warp tool or envelope distortion); you may need it to fine tune the bigger forms, but the line widths will be modified, too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cut the path with cut tool (<kbd>C</kbd>), and delete the segment in between.
2. Path eraser tool
3. Use art brushes.